Oracle SQL exclude combination of column values
I want to exclude combination of column values from the sql results.
sample table
The value of column1+column2+column3+column4 will be same as column3+column4+column1+column2 in any of the rows. I just want only one row value. Can someone help with the sql query.
I tried with where condition column1+column2+column3+column4 != column3+column4+column1+column2, it didn't work.

Here's one option; read comments within code:
SQL> WITH
  2     -- sample data
  3     test (c1,
  4           c2,
  5           c3,
  6           c4)
  7     AS
  8        (SELECT 'ABC', 1234, 'ACD', 456 FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'ACD', 456, 'ABC', 1234 FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         --
 13         SELECT 'XYZ', 123, 'MNO', 5432 FROM DUAL),

Query begins here:
 14     temp
 15     AS
 16     -- two concatenation variations
 17        (SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4, c1 || c2 || c3 || c4 cnt FROM test
 18         UNION ALL
 19         SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4, c3 || c4 || c1 || c2 cnt FROM test),
 20     temp2
 21     AS
 22     -- "sort" rows per each concatenation variation
 23        (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY cnt ORDER BY c1) rn
 24           FROM temp t)
 25    -- fetch distinct columns that ranked as the highest
 26    SELECT DISTINCT c1,
 27                    c2,
 28                    c3,
 29                    c4
 30      FROM temp2
 31     WHERE rn = 1
 32  ORDER BY c1;

C1          C2 C3          C4
--- ---------- --- ----------
ABC       1234 ACD        456
XYZ        123 MNO       5432

SQL>

